# Universal Render Pipeline 2D lighting not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

2D light sources from URP are not displayed on Android. Everything works on PC. As far as I know, URP can work on Android, but it doesn't work for me. Everything is displayed except for the light.

Answer (score 0):

check through the quality settings under project settings > quality since switching to android might've changed some quality settings involving lighting.

Also make sure that you have the URP material applied to your sprites since they require it to be lit.

Comment: I set all graphics to ultra. All objects have materials. It did not help

Comment: theres settings for those graphics settings